# Exactly match 2 rows in a tensor Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I want to calculate accuracy where I want to count number of rows which are exactly equal in 2 equal shaped tensors.

```
A = [2 1 0
     0 1 9
     1 3 4]
B = [2 1 1
     0 1 9
     1 3 4]

Accuracy = 2/3 = 0.67
```

How can I do this in TF Ops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import tensorflow as tf

A = [[2, 1, 0],
     [0, 1, 9],
     [1, 3, 4]]
B = [[2, 1, 1],
     [0, 1, 9],
     [1, 3, 4]]

x = tf.constant(A) 
y = tf.constant(B) 

result = tf.math.equal(x, y) # this compares elementwise
print(result.numpy()) # printing it as numpy array
```

It prints:

```
[[ True  True False]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]]
```

Then:

```
result = tf.reduce_all(result, axis=1) # returns True for a row if all elements in that row are True
print(result.numpy()) # printing as numpy array
```

it prints:

```
[False  True  True]
```

Then:

```
result = tf.cast(result, 'float32') # change it to numeric for calculating accuracy

print(result.numpy())
```

prints:

```
[0. 1. 1.]
```

Finally, calculate the average:

```
result = tf.reduce_mean(result) # calculate the accuracy
print(result.numpy())
```

prints:

```
0.6666667
```